# Retry mechanism in Android SyncAdapter

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I am Starting manual sync using below method

```
public void startSync(){
        Bundle syncBundle = new Bundle();
        syncBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        syncBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        syncBundle.putInt(Utils.SYNC_TYPE, USER_DATA);

        ContentResolver.requestSync(acts[0], CONTENT_AUTHORITY, syncBundle);

  }
```

**let say sync fails due some reason :**

**1. Network Failure -- How to start sync again when network comes back**

**2. Bad response from server  -- best way to retry**

**3. device shut down -- best way to restart sync when device boots up**

Is there any mechanism in sync framework of android which handles this.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For #1 and #2 you can report a "soft error" and then it should automatically retry (with exponential backoff):

```
syncResult.stats.numIoExceptions++;
```

For #4 you could create a broadcast receiver for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and then trigger your manual sync from there.